# Synonym for 'blinkered' with positive connotations

Tags: adjectives, synonyms

I want to say:

"a blinkered pursuit of pure excellence"

and was wondering if there was a more positive adjective I could use instead of 'blinkered', as it is not negative in this context. However, I want the meaning of blinkered, in that it is stronger than 'extreme focus', it is an unabashed paying of attention to only one thing to solely achieve excellence in a good way.

Comment: Single-minded..

Comment: extremely focused pursuit of excellence - can't get much more extreme!

Comment: what is pure excellence? How is it different from excellence?

Comment: @Lambie perhaps this is not the optimal way to phrase it, but I meant to contrast from people who are half pursuing excellence and half pursuing money. These people are only pursuing excellence, in a very pure way and form, desiring only the excellence.

Comment: Then, say that: the single-minded pursuit of excellence. [Thank you to Phil.]

Comment: [Lexus used **relentless**](https://www.business2community.com/branding/the-relentless-pursuit-of-perfection-the-lexus-brand-strategy-0307457) for many years, apparently to good effect.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

“Assiduous” sounds like a good substitute, or even just “hyperfocused.”

Answer (score 0):

**laser beam**  [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/laser%20beam)

> beam of light generated by a laser
>
> “Focus like a laser beam on the elections.”  LA Times OCT. 2018

As in your example:

"... a **laser beam** pursuit of pure excellence"

or

"... the pursuit of pure excellence as like a **laser beam**"

or simply use **laser** in your usages